# Missing trailing elements after an HTML form?

Tags: html

I really hope this isn't a stupid question, but this HTML seems too simple to fail.  Still, it fails.

I have a page that starts with a form, and after the form, I have some more elements.  Those elements are never displayed!  Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>CGI Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/cgi-bin/upload.cgi" target="upload_target">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="uploadBackgroundFile" />
     <p>File Upload:
     <input type="file" name="file" value="" /> (Select A Local File)</p>
     <p><input type="submit" name="cgitest" value="Submit Request" /></p>
        <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src=""
            style="visibility: hidden; width: 500px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid black;" />
    </form>
    <p />
    <hr />
    <h1>List of uploaded files:</h1>
    <ul id="listBackgroundFiles">
        <li>(Nothing loaded yet)</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, if I call "document.getElementById('listBackgroundFiles')", it returns null.  The elements after the form aren't just not displayed, they don't seem to exist at all!

This doesn't appear to be a browser issue...I get the same problem in Internet Explorer 7.0.6002.18005, Firefox 3.6.12, Chrome 5.0.375.99, Opera 10.60.3445, and Safari 5.0.2 (7533.18.5), all running (sadly) under Windows Vista.  I ran the page through the W3C and WDG validators, and those didn't show any problems.  Finally, if I move those elements above the form, they display just fine.  It seems to be an issue with putting elements after the form.

Again, I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I'm baffled by how something this simple could fail so consistently.

Comment: <p />
this is not doing anything! Or its a CSS issue?

Comment: I didnt think that self closing paragraph tags are valid?

Comment: In firefox, you can use the firebug extension to check the css and dom properties of that element. That should give you at least some clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src=""
            style="visibility: hidden; width: 500px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid black;" />
```

to

```
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src=""
            style="visibility: hidden; width: 500px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid black;" ></iframe>
```

As far as I know, `<iframes>` and `<scripts>` should always be closed by writing another closing tag, not in a single tag.

Check this link for the a list of HTML Tags, only tags that are self closed in this list, can and SHOULD be self closed: [List of HTML Tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp)

Although according to my experience, script and iframe tags are the most dangerous ones.

Comment: Same for `<p />`; That's what probably killing the rendering.

Comment: Oy...I never would have guessed that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The iframe is not self-closing. Try it like this and it will work.

```
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src=""
            style="visibility: hidden; width: 500px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid black;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though your code validates, the self closing iframe is the problem.  Change `<iframe />` to `<iframe> </iframe>`.  Just like the script tag its one of those 'things'...